# In swiftui how do i only make a navigation link active after a selection is made?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In swiftui how do i only make a navigation link active after a selection is made? I've included a screenshot. I'd like to be able to select either one option or multiple, but don't want the next button to be highlighted until at least one option is chosen.

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA618.png))

```
import SwiftUI

struct AudienceView: View {
    
    @State var isOn_w = false
    @State var isOn_m = false
    @State var isOn_g = false
    @State var isOn_b = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Audience")
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(.title2)
                .frame(
                      minWidth: 0,
                      maxWidth: .infinity,
                      alignment: .center
                    )
            
            Spacer()
            
            ScrollView{
                    


                    Toggle(isOn: $isOn_w)
                                        {Text("Women")
                                                .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                                        }
                                                .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                                    
                                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $isOn_m)
                                    {Text("Men")
                                            .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                                    }
                                            .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                    
                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $isOn_g)
                                        {Text("Girls")
                                                .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                                        }
                                                .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                    
                                    
                    Toggle(isOn: $isOn_b)
                                    {Text("Boys")
                                            .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                                    }
                                            .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                }
            NavigationLink(destination: AgeCategoryView(), label: {Text("Next")})
                .padding(.bottom)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it possible for you to create a [mre]? What you've included won't compile because there are missing types/functions. `active` in SwiftUI terms means that the `NavigationLink` has actually been visited (ie the next page is shown). Is that what you want, or are you looking to make it only clickable when one of the toggles is on?

Comment: Thank you!

Yes. I'd like it to be clickable only after at least one toggle is on. 

I'll add the code from the main app view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `.opacity()` modifier to you Navigation Link to show it only when condition is met. You can provide logic for selection like this:

```
var selectionMade: Bool {
    if isOn_w == true || isOn_m == true || isOn_g == true || isOn_b == true {
        return true 
    } else {
        return false 
    }
}
```

And than attach it to you `Navigation Link`:

```
NavigationLink(destination: AgeCategoryView(), label: {Text("Next")})
                .padding(.bottom)
                .opacity(selectionMade ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this approach using an `ObservableObject`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            AudienceView()
        }
    }
}

class AudienceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn_w = false {
        didSet { isActive = isOn_w || isOn_m || isOn_g || isOn_b }
    }
    @Published var isOn_m = false {
        didSet { isActive = isOn_w || isOn_m || isOn_g || isOn_b }
    }
    @Published var isOn_g = false {
        didSet { isActive = isOn_w || isOn_m || isOn_g || isOn_b }
    }
    @Published var isOn_b = false {
        didSet { isActive = isOn_w || isOn_m || isOn_g || isOn_b }
    }
    
    @Published var isActive = false
}

struct AudienceView: View {
    @StateObject var model = AudienceViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Audience")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.title2)
                .frame(
                    minWidth: 0,
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    alignment: .center
                )
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn_w)
                {Text("Women")
                    .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                }
                .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn_m)
                {Text("Men")
                    .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                }
                .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn_g)
                {Text("Girls")
                   .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                }
                .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
                Toggle(isOn: $model.isOn_b)
                {Text("Boys")
                    .WithDefaultButtonTextFormatting()
                }
               .WithDefaultToggleSelectedFormatting()
            }
            
            if model.isActive {
                NavigationLink("Next", destination: AgeCategoryView()).padding(.bottom)
            } else {
                Text("Next").foregroundColor(.gray).padding(.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do the "short cut" using your vars, like this:

```
if isOn_w || isOn_m || isOn_g || isOn_b {
    NavigationLink("Next", destination: AgeCategoryView()).padding(.bottom)
} else {
    Text("Next").foregroundColor(.gray).padding(.bottom)
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer